# How to separate other types for object in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I need to extract some keys from objects with special interface (like, IProps).
I want to return from function "a" only properties, which has ISubProps interface

```
interface IProps<T> {
    value: T;
}
interface ISubProps {
    [index: string]: IProps<any>;
}
interface IAnyProps {
    [index: string]: string | object | boolean | number | symbol;
}

function a<A extends ISubProps, B extends IAnyProps>(props: A & B): A { // Here !!!

    return null as any;
}

a({
    b: "hi", // error, "b" is not assignable to IProps<any>
});
```

Comment: Do you want function `a` to accept an object with properties, and each property being either `IProps<any>`as in `ISubProps`, or `string | object | whatever ` as in `IAnyProps`? If so, then you need `a` argument to be declared as a union type: `props: A | B`, not intersection type.

Comment: I want not only to accept some argument, i need to extract only required parts of that argument.